# How to get properties of items in IEnumerable<T> when that IEnumerable is in a model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

I have the following model which has an IEnumerable where T is another object/model:

```
public class Employee
{

    public ApplicationUser PayrollAdmin { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Dependant> Dependants { get; set; }

}
```

The Dependant class is essentially this:

```
public class Dependant
{

    public int DependantId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Employee_EmployeeId")]
    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }

    public int? Employee_EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

I am unable to access the Dependant properties from the Employee model.  Razor does not expose those properties.  I essentially want to do something like @Model.Employee.Dependant.FirstName but can't drill into those properties.  Is this not possible or is there something I need to do to get there?

Answer (score 3):

The `Dependants` property is a collection, so you need to iterate over it in order to access the elements of this collection separately:

```
@foreach (var dependent in Model.Employee.Dependants)
{
    <div>@dependant.FirstName</div>
    <div>@dependant.LastName</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dependants` is a collection.  You will either have to iterate over:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Employee.Dependants)
{
    <span>@item.FirstName @item.LastName</div>
}
```

or use LINQ

```
@if(Model.Employee.Dependants.Any())
{
    Model.Employeee.Dependants.FirstOrDefault().FirstName
}
```